# Webform File Upload Error: POST truncated

Tags: 7, webforms

We have a simple Webform which contains 2 components, a standard file upload and a text field allowing the user to provide a description.

We are getting the following error from time to time:

POST truncated to 1 input vars. PHP max_input_vars is 2000. Increase
max_input_vars.

The file is successfully uploaded, but sometimes this error causes problems with an additional submit handler We've added. This tends to happen with larger files, but with that being said the last failure was with a 5Mb file, but we've successfully received 6Mb files without a problem so I don't think it's a file size problem.

Comment: What happens when you increase `max_input_vars`?

Comment: I have increased the setting to 3000, I remember I had to increase the default setting from 1000 because a similar issue was happening on the modules page. Just need to wait and see if this fixes it. The main problem is that prior to yesterday the previous instance was 3 weeks ago.

Comment: @Clive so it would appear this error is generated if they try to upload an invalid file type. The form in question is limited to documents (pdf, doc, etc.) and the most recent person when this error was triggered tried to upload a JPG.

Comment: Weird. I mean, makes sense that the upload would fail, but I'd expect a better error message than you're getting